# zoom in and zoom out camera on pinch gesture swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am using front camera in my app. I want that while taking photos user can zoom in and out camera

I tried this code

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
print(sender.scale)
let vZoomFactor = sender.scale * prevZoomFactor
if sender.state == .ended {
    prevZoomFactor = vZoomFactor >= 1 ? vZoomFactor : 1
}

if sender.state == .changed{
    do {
        try device!.lockForConfiguration()
        if (vZoomFactor <= device!.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor) {
            device!.videoZoomFactor = max(1.0, min(vZoomFactor, device!.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor))
            device?.unlockForConfiguration()
        } else {
            print("Unable to set videoZoom: (max \(device!.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor), asked \(vZoomFactor))")
        }
    } catch {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

every thing is working fine in back camera but zoom is not applying on front camera.

Comment: I feel, front cameras don't support zoom in/out feature. Did you try iPhone's camera app?

Comment: yes i checked some apps like https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mirror/id431471943 , it support zoom in front camera

Comment: Ok, did you debug zoom factor values in different modes? What is failing the if condition?

Comment: yes i did nothing is failing .. in-fact when i switch to back cam it working fine when i switch to front code is working but zoom not applying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well, after spending hours on this code i got the there where i was making the mistake.

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
```

this will by default get the back camera and work perfect but when i switch it to front it is till considering it as back camera , so i just added a condition

```
    if  currentcam == frontcam {
      let device = frontcam
      //did other stuff for zooimng
     } 

   else {
     let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
     //did other stuff for zooimng
  }
```

this worked fine for me